# ckeditor 4.7.1 not saving youtube embed code

Tags: youtube, ckeditor

I am trying unsuccessfully to insert embed code into my 4.7.1 ckeditor. I click on SOURCE...paste the embed code...click source again...the video shows and I can even play the video.  When I go to save the "post" with text and video the only thing that remains is the text.  The iframe is replaced with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.  Here is my config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*};iframe(*)[*]{*}';
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to Source mode and back couple of times? Does the video say or is removed? If it is removed, please try downloading embed plugins and configuring content provider. Please see: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mediaembed.html. If embedded content stays and it is removed after saving and loading back the data, it means your server-side code is removing it and not the editor.

Comment: **Side note:**  If you are disabling ACF `config.allowedContent = true;` it means you are allowing everything to be inserted into editor. There is no point in allowing extra tags since everything is already allowed. 
This line is not needed: `config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*};iframe(*)[*]{*}';`

Comment: You were correct...I created a function to escape data before inserting into my database that employed 'strip_tags' prior to 'mysqli_real_escape_string'.  All I needed to do was add 'iframe' to my list of accepted tags.

Comment: Glad I could help.